# JavaScript "getelementsby" css trouble

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to JavaScript and CSS and am having some trouble figuring out which "getelementsby" I should use as well as what CSS type I should use.

The CSS property I'm trying to call out with the JavaScript is:

```
.restore a:link, .restore a:visited
```

On my web page, the link looks like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/coolnewstuff.html">
```

And the JavaScript I'm using is:

```
<script>
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('.restore a:link');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD register here.';
        links[i].href = 'register.php';
    }
}
</script>
```

But it is not working (I think because getelementsby is wrong.

I tried changing `.restore a:link` to just `'a'` but it replaces every single link on my page, and I only want it to replace the links inside of my post content, and only the links (not the images that link to their full sized image).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `tagName` is wrong, it should be one of standard tag names like `a`, `h1`, ...

Comment: As explained in the post: "I tried changing .restore a:link to just 'a' but it replaces every single link on my page, and I only want it to replace the links inside of my post content, and only the links (not the images that link to their full sized image)."

Comment: so you should have not even tried it, a simple solution is select all the links (of some parent) then loop through the links and filter for only the links having class `restore`.

Answer (score 8):

You should be using querySelectorAll.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.restore a:link');
```

`document.getElementByTagName()` is used to match tags by their name.